# Pattern detection in a string in Python

Tags: python, pattern-recognition

I have a list of actions described with strings, ex "`BPxPyPzPC`" where each letter represents an action and C represents an event.

Some users' actions (such as "`B`", "`Px`", "`Py`" and "`Pz`") led to an event (in my example, the letter "`C`"), others did not, so I want to identify the pattern of actions (ex "`BPxPyPz`") that most often leads to the event, what is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

Thanks!

Example code:

```
c=['' for x in range(0,4)]
c[0]="BPxPxPyPC"
c[1]="BPxPyPyPC"
c[2]="BPyPxPyPC"
c[3]="BPyPxPyPC"

#do something

#desired result
The most likely sequence of actions to achieve "C" is "BPyPxPy"
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear if and how do you want to discriminate the actions.

I used regular expressions to match any string followed by `C`, and `Counter` to get the most common string.

Here's the simplest thing to obtain your result:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

c = ["BPxPxPyPC", "BPxPyPyPC", "BPyPxPyPC", "BPyPxPyPC"]

cnt = Counter()
for sequence in c:
    m = re.match('^(.*)C$', sequence)
    if m: cnt.update([m.group(1)])

print('The most likely sequence is " {}"'.format(cnt.most_common(1)[0][0]))
# BPyPxPyP
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (takes into account only first sequence of actions that has max hits in ***stack*** for event ***ev***):

```
def checkSeq(c, stack):
    stackSeqs = [x[0] for x in stack]

    if c not in stackSeqs:
        stack.append([c,0])
    else:
        idx = stackSeqs.index(c)
        stack[idx][1] += 1
    return stack

def max_act_ev(ev, stack):
    acts=[]
    for row in stack:
        if ev in row[0][-1]:
            acts.append(row)
    if len(acts) > 0:
        res = sorted(acts, key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
        return res[0]
    else:
        return []


# Start of code

stack=[["BPyPxPyPC",1],["BPxPxPyPC",1],["BPxPxPxPC",1]]
c = "BPxPxPyPC"
ev = "C"

stack = checkSeq(c,stack)
seq = max_act_ev(ev,stack)

print(stack)
if len(seq)>0:
    print('The most likely sequence of actions to achieve "'+seq[0][-1]+'" is "'+seq[0][:-1]+'"')
else:
    print("No actions found for event "+ev)
```